# MATLAB legend icons

Tags: matlab, legend

I have a plot with three datasets on (let's call them a, b and c). Dataset a is depicted by a blue line with triangle datamarkers, b is a red line with cross datamarkers and c is a blue line with star datamarkers.

When I make a legend, the icon for a is correct and also b is fine but the icon for c is the same as dataset a.

Does anybody know why this might be happening and how to fix it?

Comment: can you post the code that reproduces the problem?

Comment: The code was legend('a','b','c'), nothing complicated just a really simple 'insert legend' command, thanks.